# MVC4 RenderViewToString not respecting mobile views

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm building mobile views for an asp.net MVC4 site and have encountered a problem. We have quite a bit of places where we have a method to convert a view into a string but this method doesn't seem to work with displaymodes thus always finding the default view. E.g. index.cshtml instead of index.mobile.cshtml.

Any ideas to what is missing to make this code respect mobile display modes?

```
public string RenderViewToString(string viewName, object model)
    {
        ViewData.Model = model;
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);

            if (viewResult.View == null)
            {
                var message = String.Format("View '{0}' not found. Searched in the following locations {1}.",
                    viewName, String.Join(", ", viewResult.SearchedLocations));
                throw new Exception(message);
            }

            var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
            viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
            return stripWhitespaceRx.Replace(sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString(), " ").Trim();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to pass a explicit argument for displaying mobile views, it doesn't know that it is mobile or not.

Comment: I figured as much, but don't know where to pass that argument. My best solution so far is to, in the viewname make sure that I try to find a mobile version first and then fallback to the default if nothing is found.

But it don't quite feel right.

Comment: You need to create something before the method call above, the viewname should be mobile or in the object (if it's a viewmodel or something create a property maybe called IsMobile, and depending on if it's mobile behave accordingly).

Comment: Ok thanks, that's also what i came up with. I just hoped there was a better solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize the parameter "viewName" with expected view.

For example before invoking RenderViewToString specify the viewName based USER AGENT of the Request object.

```
if(Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice)
{
  viewName = "~/Views/index.mobile.cshtml";
}
else
{
  viewName = "~/Views/index.cshtml";
}
```